# Fetch data from CloudKit to app when app is in background

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I have an app that uses Core Data with CloudKit to store data. When I am in the app (using the app) and create some new data on an other device, the data is fetched in a few seconds and I see it immediately, however if I am not using the app and create some new data on an other device, I have to enter the app and then the data starts fetching, is there a way to fetch data even if I am not using the app.

Here is my core data stack:

```
import CoreData
import Combine

class PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreData")
        
        guard let fileContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "APP_GROUP_NAME")?.appendingPathComponent("CoreData.sqlite") else {
            fatalError("Shared file container could not be created.")
        }
        
        let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: fileContainer)
        storeDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        storeDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "Container_Identifier")

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable remote notifications? See here; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

Comment: Yes, I enabled Background Fetch, Remote notifications, Background Processing and Push Notifications